# How to efficiently create a list of WriteModel in Mongo?

Tags: c#, database, algorithm

Rather than make a request to the database for every single document retrieved from the query. We can create a List of WriteModel operations instead.

```
var operationList = new List<WriteModel<JobInfoRecord>>();

using (var cursor = await jobInfoDocuments.Find(filter).Project(projectionDefinition).ToCursorAsync())
{
      while (await cursor.MoveNextAsync())
      {
            var batch = cursor.Current;
            foreach (var document in batch)
            {
                 var newInfo = Regex.Replace(document.SerializedInfo, regex, EmptyTag);

                 // Applying several operations within the one request.
                 operationList.Add(new UpdateOneModel<JobInfoRecord>(Builders<JobInfoRecord>.Filter.Eq("_id", document.Id),
                                                                     Builders<JobInfoRecord>.Update.Set("SerializedBackgroundJobInfo", newInfo)));
             }
```

Is it good algorithm to execute once in every 1000 and clear list?

```
if (operationList.Count <= 1000)
{
    await jobInfoDocuments.BulkWriteAsync(operationList, writeOptions);
    operationList = new List<WriteModel<JobInfoRecord>>();
}
```

And then after `while (await cursor.MoveNextAsync())` check if we didn't forgot anything

```
if (operationList.Count > 0)
{
    await jobInfoDocuments.BulkWriteAsync(operationList, writeOptions);
}
```

Or I just can do the following after `foreach` loop without any `if` statement:

```
await jobInfoDocuments.BulkWriteAsync(operationList, writeOptions);
operationList = new List<WriteModel<JobInfoRecord>>();
```

What should I do after the `foreach` loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move this blook of code inside `foreach`

```
// Execute once in every 1000 and clear list
if (operationList.Count == 1000)
{
     await jobInfoDocuments.BulkWriteAsync(operationList, writeOptions);
     operationList = new List<WriteModel<JobInfoRecord>>();
}
```

This is the best way to improve performance.

Each group of operations can have at most 1000 operations. If a group exceeds this limit, MongoDB will divide the group into smaller groups of 1000 or less. For example, if the bulk operations list consists of 2000 insert operations, MongoDB creates 2 groups, each with 1000 operations.